# android async task return type and lockdown

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have the following assynctask implemented. Its usage is pretty simple, and so works as intended so far. get a url, post to it, get its contents, write them to a file. the hard part begins now

QUESTION:
 I require reusage of this piece of code multiple times for multiple different files. How can i pass the file as a variable on assynctask call alongside the url?

```
//class to call a url and save it to a local file
        private class url_to_file extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

            protected String[] doInBackground(String... input) {
                //function to call url and postback contents
                return callpost(input[0]);
            }

            protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                //Yet to code
            }

            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                //function to write content to text file
                writeStringAsFile( result, "file.xml" ,getApplicationContext());

            }
        }
```

EDIT:
Purelly as reference, the function i use to read, write from file and call url

```
//saves a txt (etc, xml as well) file to directory,replacing previous. if directory is left empty, save to assets
    public static void writeStringAsFile(final String fileContents, String fileName ,Context context) {
        try {
            FileWriter out = new FileWriter(new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName));
            out.write(fileContents);
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    //read file, returns its contents
    public static String readFileAsString(String fileName,Context context) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        BufferedReader in = null;

        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(context.getFilesDir(), fileName)));
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) stringBuilder.append(line);

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }

    //calls a page. Returns its contents
    public String callpost (String... strings)
    {
        StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {
            // create a url object
            URL url = new URL(strings[0]);

            // create a urlconnection object
            URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();

            // wrap the urlconnection in a bufferedreader
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));

            String line;

            // read from the urlconnection via the bufferedreader
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                content.append(line + "\n");
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return content.toString();
    }
```

EDIT: 
Removed second question as it had nothing to do with the rest and would just confuse people to see the thread

Comment: Q1: maybe create a constructor and pass the needed values...[MORE](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11335798/4577762) - Q2: Do you want some sort of spinning progress bar until it's finished? [MORE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18069678/how-to-use-asynctask-to-display-a-progress-bar-that-counts-down) - this last link I didn't fully check. You'll also need to check for all the tasks.

Comment: Q1 i could see it working for my needs with a string atribute and a set function wich would boil down to the same oucome. Will try next thing tomorow. As for Q2 im not so fussy about the visual part i will figure that out. The question is how could i give the main thread to understand that all calls finished and it can continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kudos @FirstOne for his help up at comments

this made it for me

```
 //class to call a url and save it to a local file
            private class url_to_file extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {
              protected String file;
              public void setFile(String input)
              {
                 file=input;
              }

                protected String[] doInBackground(String... input) {
                    //function to call url and postback contents
                    return callpost(input[0]);
                }

                protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
                    //Yet to code
                }

                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                    //function to write content to text file
                    writeStringAsFile( result, file ,getApplicationContext());

                }
            }
```